# ASP.NET gridview does not allow me to click on column header texts so I can sort the data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I'm just trying to allow the user to sort the GridView by any of the columns of it.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShows" runat="server" DataKeyNames="dataSource,title" Caption="Show List" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowPaging="True" CaptionAlign="Left" OnSorting="gvShows_Sorting" >
                    <RowStyle BorderColor="Black" />
                    <Columns> 
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select"> 
                            <ItemTemplate> 
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelect" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false"/> 
                            </ItemTemplate> 
                        </asp:TemplateField> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Data Source" DataField="dataSource" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Show ID" DataField="ShowId" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Show Title" DataField="title" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Episode Id" DataField="EpisodeID" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Episode Title" DataField="EpisodeTitle" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Genre" DataField="Genre" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Show Type Description" DataField="ShowTypeDescription" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Director Name" DataField="DirectorName" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Release Year" DataField="ReleaseYear" /> 
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Season Episode" DataField="SeasonEpisode" /> 
                    </Columns>  
                </asp:GridView>

    protected void gvShows_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataTable = Session["shows"] as DataTable;

        if (dataTable != null)
        {
            var dataView = new DataView(dataTable)
                {
                    Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + ConvertSortDirection(e.SortDirection)
                };

            gvShows.DataSource = dataView;
            gvShows.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private string ConvertSortDirection(SortDirection sortDirection)
    {
        string newSortDirection = String.Empty;

        switch (sortDirection)
        {
            case SortDirection.Ascending:
                newSortDirection = "ASC";
                break;

            case SortDirection.Descending:
                newSortDirection = "DESC";
                break;
        }

        return newSortDirection;
    }
```

When data is displayed in the GridView, I'm simply not allowed to click on the header text so that I can sort the data:

[image]

Comment: See if this helps.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms745786(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I got it. I needed to add SortExpressions because the columns are not generated automatically.

Comment: Heres a related article do refer http://satindersinght.blogspot.in/2013/05/gridview-sorting-on-header-click-with.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I needed to add SortExpressions because the columns are not generated automatically.

Comment: You should select Fabzien's answer - he gave you the correct answer before you posted your answer...  Credit where credit is due

Answer (score 6):

You need to add "**SortExpression**" in your asp:BoundField.

For example :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
```