# How do I make my asp.net gridview able to sort?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

Okay so here is the big question that I have been working on for hours now.

I got my gridview and I got a header that will always stay at top that I use jQuery for the header, I got at the top always wont get the hyperlinks from gridview allow sorting.

I know that I can sort the gridview by adding: `ORDER BY` ColumnName. But I don't know how to create the click event or how to display an arrow (if possible) so you can see if it's in ascending or descending. Also if you click it it will change from ascending/descending

My code is so far:

Side.aspx

```
            <div id="GHead"></div>
            <div style="overflow: auto; height: 100%">
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" BackColor="White" Width="100%" BorderColor="#CC9966" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateSelectButton="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tildelt" DataField="Tildelt" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Firma" DataField="Firma" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Kontakt" DataField="Kontakt" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Svar" DataField="Svar" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Emne" DataField="Emne" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Due Date" DataField="DueDate" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Prioritet" DataField="Prioritet" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Status" DataField="Status" />
                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Lukke Dato" DataField="Lukke Dato" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#FFFFCC" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFFFCC" ForeColor="#330099" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#330099" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#663399" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FEFCEB" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#AF0101" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F6F0C0" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#7E0000" />
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

jQuery code

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script lang="ja">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true); //clone copy of gridview with style
        $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // removes all rows except first row
        $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
            //sets width of each th from gridview
            $("th:nth-child("+(i+1)+")",gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width() + 1).toString() + "px");
        });
        $("#GHead").append(gridHeader);
        $('#GHead').css('position', 'absolute');
        $('#GHead').css('top', $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>").offset().top);

    });
</script>
```

I got all the jQuery from the internet.

Here is what it looks like now.
[image]

Comment: why don't you use gridview's built-in sorting event?

Comment: by that you mean AllowSorting="true"? cuz I tried that and nothing is happening cuz of the jquary code so it will stay on top even if scrolled down if its not what you ment can you come with a example for it?

Comment: No he meant You need to add gridview onsorting event and do the sorting at server side.

Comment: Microsoft recommends you don't style your controls using the syntax you used. Instead, you should be using CSS. While you're at it, why don't you consider just replacing the GridView with a repeater, then use something like [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) that has excellent sorting, filtering, and styling built in?

Comment: Well if I just can make my headers clickable and run a sql quary I got my sorting done there.
And if I go to a repeater I see that I am able to make the table items into hyperlink and so on but, The header wont stay at top again so basicly it will have the same problem then what I had on this one at first.
It all worked fine but then the company that wanted the program said that the header should allways be at top thats why the jquary got in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution how to make them clickable. sinse they arent automaticly generated I needed to put in SortExpression for each boundfield.

Did not find it out myself I found [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17158405/asp-net-gridview-does-not-allow-me-to-click-on-column-header-texts-so-i-can-sort) where he had a problem just like me and with a answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AllowSorting` proprty to do what do you want and do not use third-party tools like jQuery when framework has standard functionality to do it.

For example:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SomeGridView" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" Width="100%" AllowPaging="True"
    PageSize="50" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="SomeGridView_OnPageIndexChanging"
    OnSorting="SomeGridView_OnSorting" OnRowDataBound="SomeGridView_OnRowDataBound">
```

Comment: did not help me at all... what I wanted was not to change my scrolling grid into a paging grid

Comment: seems like you only saw the pictures and code and did not want to read what was the problems. if you look at my code I have allowsorting and it wont work cuz of the JQuary and I need the JQuary to keep the header at top at all time unless someone can come up with a great solution there. 
The allowsorting wont get transfered to the JQuary